# Assign user roles to users when register wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using 'Woo Discount Rules Pro' plugin to offer discounts for different user categories.

In the user registration page, I have included an input field to get the category of the user.

[image]

Although the category is saving inside the user profile, the role of the user is saved as 'customer' since I gave the default role as 'customer'.

[image]

What I need to achieve is save the relevant category of the user which user selects(i.e. school, uni, office) under 'User Role' when the user registers.

I tried to look into some plugins which perform this action when the user registers.

I found a plugin called [Registration Magic](https://registrationmagic.com/) and that would solve my issue. But unfortunately, it is not free and has to pay to unlock this specific feature.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this action with or without a plugin? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate Member plugin assigns default role to a new user via this hook:

```
add_action('um_after_new_user_register', 'um_after_new_user_register', 10, 2);
```

and rewrite the roles of new user:

...

```
$ultimatemember->user->set_role( $role );
```

...
You can add your own routine with lower priority, like

```
add_action('um_after_new_user_register', 'custom_after_new_user_register', 20, 1);
function custom_after_new_user_register($user_id) {
  $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  if (!in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
    $user->add_role('subscriber');
  }
}
```

WordPress will execute it after UM and new user will receive the additional role.

I did not tested this code, wrote it from scratch, just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named [Wp Role at Registration](https://li.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-roles-at-registration/) and it has solved this issue. Most of all it's a free plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign user role on signup using **User Registration** wordpress plugin : https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/

- install it
- create form with it and then go to form settings
  [image]